# When the range is too large it generates an error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas

The code below works with up to 8000 lines. More than that, it generates the error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

The df is ordered by 'ID'. I need to fill the 'ENTRADA' column with the 'ID' enumeration.

ID ... ENTRADA

150 ...      1

150 ...      2

150 ...      3

151 ...      1

152 ...      1

152 ...      2

Is there an easier way to do this?

```
def preencheEntrada():
    id_documento = 0
    numEntrada = 0
    for i in range(len(df)) : 
        valor_id_documento = df.loc[i, 'ID']
        if (id_documento == valor_id_documento) :
            numEntrada = numEntrada + 1
        else :
            id_documento = valor_id_documento
            numEntrada = 1
        df.loc[i, 'ENTRADA'] = numEntrada
```

Comment: Where is the error? Please always post the full error message including the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `pandas` like this, instead, always try to opt for vectorized operations.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [150, 150, 150, 151, 152, 152]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
    ID
0  150
1  150
2  150
3  151
4  152
5  152

In [4]: df.groupby('ID').cumcount()
Out[4]:
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    0
4    0
5    1
dtype: int64
```

So, if you have to start at `1`, you can do something like:

```
In [5]: df["ENTRADA"] = df.groupby("ID").cumcount() + 1

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
    ID  ENTRADA
0  150        1
1  150        2
2  150        3
3  151        1
4  152        1
5  152        2
```

In any case, the error you were getting doesn't make a whole lot of sense, it shouldn't depend on the length of your dataframe, without a reproducible example, we can only speculate.